# Prepend and append to each variable

Tags: php, regex

First question here!

I have some PHP variables all in the form of the below, in around 7/8 different files.

```
$this->do['string']
```

I wish to make them all into the following:

```
myfunction($this->do['string'])
```

I understand I have to use regex and the get file contents function, but I'm unsure where to go from here! Would be very grateful if someone can assist!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$result = preg_replace("/(\$this->do\['[^']+'\])/", "myfunction($1)", $inputstring);
```

**Edit according to comment:**

In the comment you said that your input string is: `$inputstring = "\$this->do['fsdfs']";` (with a backslash before `$this`). You have then to add the backslash in the regex and also escape it, so the whole instruction becomes:

```
$result = preg_replace("/(\\\$this->do\['[^']+'\])/", "myfunction($1)", $inputstring);
//                        ^^^
```

Comment: That's brilliant! So I assume I'd get the file contents, put that in $inputstring, and in $result I'd have my new file?

Comment: @Abitnew: Yes, it'll work unless you have nested functions.

Comment: Hmm not afraid I follow, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Abitnew: for example it will not work if you have something like: `$this->do['$this->do[\'...\']']`

Comment: Ah OK, no that's fine, it's only a string in the square brackets! I just gave it a quick go using: $inputstring = "\$this->do['fsdfs']";

$result = preg_replace("/(\$this->do\['[^']+'\])/", "myfunction($1)", $inputstring);
echo $result; but it didn't change anything, any idea why?

Comment: hmm, appears to be a problem with the regex but I can't see exactly what, looks right to me?

Comment: The regex should be `/(\\\$this->do\['[^']+'\])/` (note the triple slash before $ to escape properly)

Comment: Agreed! I made the edit a few minutes before you suggested it, but it appears to have been removed, don't know why, it won't work otherwise.